# forbid access to public List's methods

Tags: c#, oop

This is an extremely simplified issue description. Given that I have this:

```
interface IMyClass {
    IList<int> MyList { get; set; }
    void AddToList(int newVal);
}

public class MyClass: IMyClass {
    public IList<int> MyList { get; set; }
    public void AddToList(int newVal)
    {
        // custom implementation goes here
        MyList.Add(newVal);
    }
}
```

I was given an interface `IMyClass`, which I can not change. The task is to implement this interface, along with `addToList` method.

The problem is that even if I implement `addToList` method - there is still a possibily for the user to add items through the direct access of the `MyList` property!

Is there a way to forbid user using `Add()`, `Remove()`, `Insert()` on a list directly?

So far, I have tried implementing a custom `MyList<T>` class, but the problem there is that I have to implement every possible `IList<T>` method, but I only need a custom implementation for some of them, not all.. Or are there any other approaches?

Comment: You should make MyList property private.

Comment: Grant access to a readonly list based on your list and make your list private

Comment: Ummm... I'm going to take the contrarian point and say: You shouldn't do this at all.  You're looking at it as, "Hey, this is breaking encapsulation, and letting anyone set my list from anywhere."  But... that's what the Interface is *indicating*.  If I'm programming and using something that implements that interface, I'm going to *expect* that I can either add items one at a time, or set the full list directly.  If you do what you're trying to do, you're basically *breaching* the contract - you're making it behave differently that the interface indicates.

Comment: To expand the previous comment a bit: imagine you had List<IMyClass>.  You should be able to loop through that list, calling the Set on each item.MyList.  And it work... unless one of the items on the list was your particular implementation of the interface (that blocks list setting functionality).  The more I think about this, the more I think: The interface might have problems, but if you can't *change* it, and if you *have* to implement it with your class, you should implement it according to its specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the list private and not expose it to the consumer. This way, the consumer cannot modify your list.

Also, by using IReadOnlyList, the consumer doesn't even HAVE add or remove.

```
private List<int> myList;
public IReadOnlyList<int> MyList => myList.ToArray();
```

However, converting to Array each time does come at a performance penalty. If you do not want to waste resources, and you absolutely cannot change the interface, you need to create your own IList implementation:

```
public class MyClass: IMyClass {
    private IList<int> myInnerList;
    public IList<int> MyList { get; }


    MyClass() 
    {
        myInnerList = new List<int>();
        MyList = new ProtectedList(myInnerList);
    }

    public void AddToList(int newVal)
    {
        myInnerList.Add(newVal);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Encapsulates an IList in a way, so that you can only change it
/// through the original IList reference.
/// </summary>
class ProtectedList<T> : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private IList<T> innerList;
    public ProtectedList(IList<T> innerList) => this.innerList = innerList;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => innerList[index];
        set => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    public int Count => innerList.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => true;
    public void Add(T item) => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public void Clear() => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public bool Contains(T item) => innerList.Contains(item);
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => innerList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => innerList.GetEnumerator();
    public int IndexOf(T item) => innerList.IndexOf(item);
    public void Insert(int index, T item) => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public bool Remove(T item) => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    public void RemoveAt(int index) => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => innerList.GetEnumerator();
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, but in the intercase I have `IList<int>` therefore I can not implement it as `IReadOnlyList<int>`..

Comment: Array also implements ilist so the above approach works. If performance is key, however, you should create your own ilist implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you cannot change the interface you'll have to live with the property being exposed as public `IList<int>`. Even if you implement the interface explicitly (to hide the public property) nothing prevents the user from casting an instance to the type of the interface to access the public `IList<int>` property.

But since the [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the `IList<T>` interface you can use it for creating a read-only wrapper around a private list, so you can expose only that read-only wrapper through the public property, but keep your actual list private, thus preventing the users from changing it. For example like this:

```
interface IMyClass {
    IList<int> MyList { get; set; }
    void AddToList(int newVal);
}

public class MyClass: IMyClass {
    private readonly List<int> myPrivateList;

    public IList<int> MyList { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Create private list used internally
        myPrivateList = new List<int>();

        // Create read-only wrapper around myPrivateList used for the public MyList property
        MyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(myPrivateList);
    }

    public void AddToList(int newVal)
    {
        // Use myPrivateList instead of MyList
        myPrivateList.Add(newVal);
    }
}
```

Though this might be a bit misleading for other developers, so IMHO a solution like this should be properly documented on the implementation.

Comment: I think you should mention that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` throws on any attempt to change the collection - depending on the OP's use case that might be exactly what he wants, or he might want to avoid that and silently swallow such attempts.

Comment: Hmm, I need to run some tests. I also found a method for list called `AsReadOnly()` which is returning a read-only collection. This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a wrapper around `IList<T>` that implements the `IList<T>` interface. This wrapper would delegate all functionality to its internal `IList<T>` and just prohibit manipulating that list directly. Something like:

```
public MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private IList<T> innerList;
    public MyList(IList<T> innerList) { this.innerList = innerList; }

    // valid operations are just delegated to the inner list...
    public int Count { get { return innerList.Count; } }
    // those you want to prohibit either do nothing or throw - depends on your desired outcome
    public void Add(T item) { return; }

    // and so on ...
}
```